# Django's Generic Views: how to filter get_queryset based on foreign class attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I've been following Django starter tutorial ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial05/ )

I decided to make some modifications to test my skills as of now.

Specifically I intend to implement a custom **get_queryset** for **ResultsView** generic view.

Something like this:

```
# views.py
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        '''
        Make sure we are displaying results for choices which have 1+ votes
        '''
        return Question.objects.get ...
```

Basically my goal is to return Questions' choices only for choices with **at least 1 vote**.

So I tried in Django's shell something like this:

```
# Django shell
q = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
q.choice_set.filter(votes=1)
[<Choice: Not much>]
```

Here I get question with pk = 1, then filter based on choice_set (of Choice model, whose fk refers to Question model).

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this in my **views.py**, so that it returns Questions' content (i.e. choices) only for choices with 1+ votes (i.e. displaying all choices with related votes but choices with 0 votes).

Just for completeness here is the actual template (polls/results.html):

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li> {# pluralize used to automatically add "s" for values with 0 or 2+ choice.votes #}
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

**Models**

```
# models.py
Class Question(models.Model): 

    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):             
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think __ relations should do you.

Something like this maybe?

```
def get_queryset(self):

    return Question.objects.filter(choices__votes__gte=1)
```

EDIT:

You actually want to overload get_object.  See the definitions of get() and get_object here: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Specifically, something like:

```
pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
Choice.objects.filter(question__pk=pk, votes__gte=1)
```

What you are doing is a little weird because detail view usually works on one object, but this should work.

Comment: sounds a good solution. However I get this error "get() returned more than one Question -- it returned 2!"
How to return (in get_queryset) choices with 1+ votes for the SPECIFIC question that's view is applied to?

Comment: If the view has the question PK (or something like it) you might do:  Choice.objects.filter(question__pk=X, votes__gte=1).  It depends on your models.  If you post them, it will be easier to answer.

Comment: I think the pk is implicit. I just modified my question with the 2 involved models. any clue?

Comment: While the effect is not exactly the same I wanted (I will achieve it at template-level I guess) I finally solved by using distinct(). The issue was that when performing the query for each choice with 1+ vote, the same question was returned into an array. Thanks for the effort :)